# Prevent file handles from closing at end of execution

Tags: php, file, handlers

Is there any way through which I can prevent a opened file handle from closing even the PHP finishes the code execution?
I wanna store handles in cookies (or some local file) to reuse them in another script (or after refresh) .

PS: I cannot re-open files each time.
I need to keep the file/pipe opened for a long time.

Comment: Can you add a code example of what you have already tried?

Comment: @McWayWeb I can't find any way to do so.

Comment: You can't store file handles in cookies. Resources are tied to a specific process.

Comment: There is no way to keep file handles after script ends.

Comment: Almost anything can be stored in session, except resources like file handles or database connections, but in a cookie? That would be a security breach of enormous magnitude.

Comment: But "Execute and terminate" is the PHP web model..... why can't you re-open files each request?

Comment: Because it's a pipe.
A STDIN pipe & I can't reopen it everytime. There must be anyway to save handlers somewhere.

Comment: @Hritik - There isn't a way to persist a resource. The best option I can suggest is run a daemon process that maintains the connection to that pipe, and your scripts connect to the daemon on each request

Comment: That is not how PHP works. Once the process ends then everything is 'cleaned up' / 'freed'. It would help us to provide a more useful answer if you explained what the original task was that you are trying to solve. And why PHP may be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File handles are operating system constructs, they can't be stored in a database, cookie, file, etc and then still be in any way meaningful.  In other words, no, you can't store a file handle (or anything else that's classified as a Resource)

I'd recommend finding a better solution, as you almost certainly don't have to hold a file handle open to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: But they are stored somewhere during execution, then why not after it?

Comment: Because they're essentially pointers to a file descriptor.  Once the file descriptor isn't needed any more it's destroyed and now it's a pointer into a random region of memory that may or may not even be allocated to PHP next time it runs.

Comment: @Hritik, PHP automatically frees all resources at the end of 'the run' which is at the 'end of the outer script'. This is a 'good thing' for PHP programmers. It can, and will, make 'persistence' awkward. It is a 'trade off' that PHP made. 'Swings and Roundabouts' - no easy answer.